# Why is the "Similar questions" prompt delayed?

Tags: discussion, user-experience

Why do "Similar Questions" not show up until after constructing a full question with the new SO question format?

I just posted a question on SO and was greeted with a new question format. Namely, rather than `Title`, `Body`, `Tags`, questions now are (at least was for me just earlier) `Title`, `What went wrong?`, `What did you expect?`, `Tags`. When writing the question I was not prompted to compare my question with "Similar questions" until after completing the question and adding tags to my post.

I believe this is a poor user experience as an asker may spend a considerable time crafting a post, only to be prompted that there is a similar question that solves their issue, that they had not found before.

This may have been a case of A/B testing as I am no longer greeted with the said question format.

Comment: I think this is explained in the announcement: [Ask Wizard for New Users Feature Test is now Live](/q/416735/4642212) and is [already being discussed](/a/416748/4642212).

Comment: Ah yep, that would do it, cheers @SebastianSimon